# RF Solutions ZULU module

Tags: rf, digital-communications

I am trying to set up a remote battery voltage checker that will radio the voltage read from the battery to a computer. I went for the ZULU module (by mistake as I should have brought the ZULU-M module) from RF Solutions, the link to the datasheet is below.

[Zulu datasheet](http://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/acatalog/DS-ZULU-2.pdf)

The datasheet does not seem to say to much about how much setting up of the registers is needed (if any). Some pins (like pin 3) say they can be controlled by the registers in the easyradio pro but how would I go about setting these?

The unit says it is a plug and play unit, so does this mean I can attach an input to the Rx pin and it should send what is recieved there and if not how do I go about programming the unit i.e. have they got a way of flashing the program memory like PIC have an ICSP header for programming.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

It does definitely sound like you should have gone for the ZULU-M module - that one is plug and play (almost - it needs an external crystal) and would send data fed into via low level RS232 directly to another ZULU-M module.

The ZULU bare board version is basically an application circuit of the SiLabs SI1000 chipset - it is just like buying the chip with the RF matching done for you - nothing else. The datasheet shows which pins from the chipset are brought out where etc but you would need to design a board and use the dev kit from SiLabs to get it to do anything. the Si1000 seems to be n 8051 core with a Si4431 attached to it so as you say - like a pic but with an added RFIC.